# Can't run a package after installing it using pip

Tags: terminal, pip

I have run the following command on a MacOS terminal:

pip install --user git+https://github.com/cwerner/fastclass.git#egg=fastclass

which seemingly installed that on my system (and according to the documentation added it to my PATH)

However, when I try to call the command 'fcd' it always says "command not found". I have tried to add the path of the file fcd (which is /Library/Python/2.7/bin) to my PATH using export, which works however, I still get 'command not found'.

I feel like there is something obvious I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Is fcd present in /Library/Python/2.7/bin? If not, maybe your pip is using a different python installation. If the documentation says it adds to your PATH, perhaps you need to open a new terminal window (it may have adjusted your .profile to add the path).

Comment: List installed files: `pip show --files fastclass`. Try running with the full path: `/Library/Python/2.7/bin/fcd`

Comment: I think the issue was that I wasn't including the full path e.g. Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7/bin/fcd